# Xcode 12 won't allow ⌘⌥← / ⌘⌥→ shortcuts for "Show Previous Tab" / "Show Next Tab"

Tags: xcode, xcode12

I am trying to customize the Xcode 12.2 keyboard shortcuts for **"Show Previous Tab"** and **"Show Next Tab"**. These are the new *document* tabs that were introduced in Xcode 12, as opposed to the old *window* tabs. (The document tab bar is below the window tab bar.)

When I go to Preferences > Key Bindings, and try to record shortcuts for "Show Previous Tab" and "Show Next Tab", the settings panel records **⌘⌥← as ⌘← and ⌘⌥→ as ⌘→**. Basically, the option key disappears.

This is a problem *only* for those two shortcuts. If I try to customize "Show Previous *Window* Tab" and "Show Next *Window* Tab", I can record ⌘⌥← / ⌘⌥→ just fine.

Previously, I used System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts to customize "Show Previous Tab" / "Show Next Tab" for "All Applications". I removed this, and it still didn't fix this issue in Xcode.

Comment: I'm sympathetic but I don't see how this is a programming question.

Comment: The Stack Overflow guidelines say you can ask questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" – https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to change Navigation Style to "Open in Place" in the Xcode preferences. Then the whole silly tabs in tabs thing will go away and you can go back to just using App shortcuts like you used to.

For the record, I previously used shortcuts defined in Xcode, where it actually was possible to define option as a part of a shortcut for Show next and show previous tab, but had to go with App shortcuts now due to the behaviour you describe.

This is the article where I found the above info: https://www.jessesquires.com/blog/2020/07/24/how-to-fix-the-incomprehensible-tabs-in-xcode-12/

Comment: Also, the dev forums had a question where I first found it since I thought it was the option key for all shortcuts. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/668953?login=true&page=1#652466022

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: I had to use the system preferences -> keyboard -> shortcuts and set all four of these shortcuts. Which had a weird lag when it was setting them.

- Show Previous Tab
- Show Next Tab
- Previous Window Tab
- Next Window Tab

Long version: I tried the below first which should be the correct answer but it didn't work for me. Please let me know if it works for you.

I wish this worked because it looks like it would be awesome.

XCode -> Preferences -> Key Bindings

Use the the search Filter on the right side to search for:

- Show Previous Tab
- Show Next Tab
- Previous Window Tab
- Next Window Tab